# Distance on a ring

Tags: c

I work with objects that are marked by sequential unsigned numbers. When number reaches max value, it becomes 0 again. To detect breaches in the numbering, I calculate distances between them (b is some number that arrives after a, and may be a or ==a).

```
int
distance(unsigned short a, unsigned short b)
{
  int t = (b >= a) ? b - a : USHRT_MAX - a + b + 1;
  if (t > USHRT_MAX/2 + 1)
    t -= USHRT_MAX + 1;
  return t;
}
```

This function gives correct results, but looks overcomplicated. Can you suggest a better way or is it ok like that?

Comment: `a < b` is guaranteed?

Comment: No. What is guaranteed is that b occured at some point after a, and that breach is not bigger than 2^16-1.

Comment: What are you trying to compute?  Is it the shortest distance between `a` and `b`, or the distance that b is in front of a?  For example, if `a=0` and `b=65535`, is the distance `1` or `65535`?

Comment: @ZuOverture: Your code computes `distance(5, 3) = -2`, is that intentional? If yes, why?

Comment: Yes, this is intentional. The sign shows when something caused the inversion of ordering, and 5 arrived before 3. This is treated differently further in the code than situation when 5 arrived immediately after 3.

Comment: @ZuOverture: You said above that it *"is guaranteed is that b occured at some point after a"*, so with a=5 and b=3 I would expect that b wrapped around, and d(5, 3) is 2^16 - 2.

Comment: I was not very clear, sorry. That statement was about "order of arrival", not "generation order". I have no control over generation.

Comment: Then why is distance(5, 3) negative, but distance(65535, 3) positive? – Perhaps you can clarify what your function *exactly* computes, with some examples that demonstrate the various cases. At present it is unclear (at least to me). *"detect breaches in the numbering"* and *"b is some number that goes after a"* are a bit vague.

Comment: I second @MartinR — it's really hard to understand what you actually mean. Do you need the shortest distance between two given numbers calculated both with and without stepping over zero (so `d(0,1)=d(1,0)=d(65535,0)=1`)? Or maybe you need the distance `b-a` normalized to minimum nonnegative modulo `65536` (so `d(0,1)=1` but `d(1,0)=d(0,65535)=65535`)?

Comment: You should also clarify if the wrap-around is at 65536 or at (USHRT_MAX+1) – those numbers need not be the same.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Breach is the violation of sequence order. It may be a skipped value (or many of them), or repeating value, or value arriving with delay (3 after 5). Small breaches are more likely to happen than large ones. Thus I compare modules of differences between a and b in case wraparound happened and not happened, and return the result corresponding to smallest value, because it's more probable, and I can't distinguish distances that differ by N*65536 anyways. So it's shortest distance on a ring of numbers (ring is 65536 values long) with sign.

Comment: @ZuOverture: But then `distance(0, 65535)` should be -1 and not 65535.

Comment: This is screaming for examples/unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [your answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178827/distance-on-a-ring#comment339471_178827) to [the comment by JS1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178827/distance-on-a-ring#comment339465_178827) I understand you need a difference `b-a` normalized to the range [0, USHRT_MAX] modulo (USHRT_MAX+1).

If so, you can just do

```
  return b >= a ? b - a : USHRT_MAX - a + b + 1;
```

Comment: This gives incorrect result for distance(1,0). Should be -1, returns 65535.

Comment: @ZuOverture I'm sorry, but It gives perfectly correct result according to my assumptions. And I had to make _some_ (and I did make them explicit), because you haven't had specified yours.

Comment: I've tried to clarify it as much as possible in my last comment, dunno if it finally was clear enough. Basically, ring distance isn't something exotic in mathematics. I even hoped there's standard function for its calculation.

Comment: @CiaPan: That is the dilemma when an "unclear" question is answered: The answer might not help because the suggested code is not what OP expects. On the other hand, OP is (usually) not allowed to edit the question and update his/her code after receiving answers. (Just stating, not criticizing!)

Comment: Ok, to sum up: first variant of distance() was not doing what was later stated in comments. It was fixed using CiaPan's code (thanks!), with addition of sign calculation, question modified accordingly, but I doubt it needs extra answers now. Thanks for your time, MartinR, CiaPan.

Comment: @MartinR That's not a problem at all. Not for me, at least. I'm usually ready to expand my answer by another variant if OP specifies missing assumptions (and notifies me). And I'm not against editing questions to narrow them down, as long as such modifications are done as _addendum_ or _explanation_ and do not _replace_ the original statement (even if the original statement was wrong and misleading). That's also the reason I usually try to explicitly specify assumptions I add to the problem specification when making my solutions.